# How to add a filter in SliverGrid to show only part of the StreamBuilder result

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a **SliverGrid** that populates with the result of a **StreamBuilder** from Firestore.

Right now I have other screens where I can filter the results by category, but that means a request to Firebase everytime the user pick a category, because I make the filter in the query.

So Im thinking if there is any way I can filter the results "locally" in the app, instead of making another call to the server, since all the info is already loaded.

My question is, if there any way to add a filter in the "SliverGrid" to show only the results that meet the criteria?

This is the part of my code with the Stream and the **SliverGrid**:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION')
            .orderBy('updated_at', descending: true)
            .where('status', isEqualTo : 'published')
            .snapshots(),

    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
            );
        }
        return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
                SliverGrid(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.3,
                        ),
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                        (context, index) {

                            return InkWell(
                                child: CustomWidget();
                            );
                        },
                        childCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        );
    }),
);
```

Comment: you can save it to SQL lite when data is loaded

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution was easier than I thought.

I added a **DropdownButton** that updates the state **dropdownValue** onChanged.

Also, I replaced the query in the **stream** with a variable that have a filter depending of the **dropdownValue** value.

Here is the code of the SliverGrid with the filter:

```
String dropdownValue = 'all';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var menuItems = {
        '1': 'option 1',
        '2': 'option 2',
        '3': 'option 3'
    };

    var firestoreQuery;
    if (dropdownValue == 'all'){
        firestoreQuery = (
            Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION')
            .orderBy('updated_at', descending: true)
            .where('status', isEqualTo : 'published')
            .snapshots()
        );
    }else{
        firestoreQuery = (
            Firestore.instance.collection('COLLECTION')
            .orderBy('updated_at', descending: true)
            .where('fielt_to_filter', isEqualTo : dropdownValue)
            .where('status', isEqualTo : 'published')
            .snapshots()
        );
    }

    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestoreQuery,

        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                );
            }
            return CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [

                    SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child:  <Widget>[
                            Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                children: <Widget>[ DropdownButton(
                                    value: dropdownValue,
                                    items: menuItems.entries
                                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                            (MapEntry<String, String> e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                                    value: e.key,
                                                    child: Text(e.value),
                                                ))
                                        .toList(),
                                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                        setState(() {
                                            dropdownValue = newValue;
                                        });
                                    },
                                ),
                                ]
                            ),
                    ),
                    SliverGrid(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            childAspectRatio: 1.3,
                            ),
                        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                            (context, index) {

                                return InkWell(
                                    child: CustomWidget();
                                );
                            },
                            childCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            );
        }),
    );
}
```